# How to get logs in an ios flutter app running on a physical device?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

I use [logger](https://pub.dev/packages/logger) to output information on the comand line. To access the logs remotely I use [AppSpector](https://appspector.com). This works fine while my iPhone is connected to my mac. In this case I can see the log message on the terminal anyways. When sharing the app via Test Flight I only can see a few log messages from plugins but no message from the flutter logger.

Comment: I have the same question I'm a begginer IOS developper. Not having logs makes it really hard to create applications.